# SKConstraint.position, but, for the "whole object" rather than center?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

Imagine you have a simple SpriteKit scene with say 10 round circles.  They are **all different sizes** from 1 to 10 cm.

Let's say you want to make a constraint for Apple's hard constraint pass, to keep them within a box.

Thanks to Apple this is easy.....

```
extension SKConstraint {

    static func simpleBox(_ w: CGFloat, _ h: CGFloat)->SKConstraint {

        let hw = w/2, hh = h/2
        let rx = SKRange(lowerLimit: -hw, upperLimit: hw)
        let ry = SKRange(lowerLimit: -hh, upperLimit: hh)

        return SKConstraint.positionX(rx, y: ry)
    }
}
```

(Of course to add that constraint to a SKSpriteNode, it's just...)

```
    keeper = SKConstraint.simpleBox(scene!.size.width,scene!.size.height)
    self.constraints = [keeper]
    keeper.enabled = true
```

HOWEVER,

of course, that keeps ***the centers*** of the 10 circles within the box.

Naturally, what you typically want is that the "whole" of each item stays within the box.

1. of course, if all the circles are the same size, you can just make the box smaller all around by the radius; however I'm talking about when the circles are all different sizes
2. obviously if they bounce you can use colliders at the edges, but that's not the point, I'm asking about the constraint pass

Is there a solution?  **Is there perhaps "custom" constraints** - much as you can have **custom fields**?

What's the deal on this ?

Comment: they have a distance constraint,  just do the desired distance  (e.g. length of box / 2)  - radius of circle

Comment: ah - wait - you're just saying, **do a different SKConstraint for each item!**  I guess that's the solution, it seems inefficient?

Comment: Your code is already doing a different constraint each time,  same value but different instance

Comment: your other option is to just use the physics engine and form an invisible box that the circles can't escape from

Comment: knight - sure, I mentioned doing that (point 2.), it's not an absolute constraint

Comment: I would use the physics engine for this... or give each circle a constraint

Comment: @Fluidity lol, both have been mentioned